# Buscar un valor en un rango VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

estoy diseñando un secuenciador de salidas con un código VBA cuya función es la siguiente. Debe buscar una valor introducido en una fila (en este caso la fila Z empezando pro Z4 y terminando en Z15) y debe comprobar que este valor no exista en otra fila (En este caso la fila AB, comenzando en AB4 y terminando en AB15). Si no encuentra el valor debe situar este valor en la celda en la celda correspondiente de la columna AB (e.g. Z4 --> AB4, Z5 --> AB5). Esta es una manera de asegurarse de que no existe ninguna celda AB que contenga un valor igual a otro que ya existe (entendemos los valores AB como un turno, de forma que n ose repita nturnos y haya una diferencia de 2 minutos entre turnos). Si encuentra el valor, debe añadir dos minutos a este tiempo y volver a comprobar si el turno esta libre, si es así lo sitúa en la columna AB y sino vuelve a añadir dos miuntos hasta encontrarlo.

En el código de abajo, se puede ver un statement repetitivo para cada fila Z y al final la función llamada en cada statement

Este código funciona, pero en ocasiones presenta un error, no se muy bien porque cuando los tiempos no se introducen secuencialmente de arriba a abajo salta el error "Run-time error 457:This key is already associated with an element of this collection, lo que lo mismo, "Esta clave ya está asociada a un elemento de esta colección (error 457)" y subraya la linea de código de de la función al final del código "Dict.Add Hora, 1". Parece que el orden introduciendo la data desencadena algún error. Introduzco una imagen para clarificarlo 
[image: Ejemplo de secuenciador]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim HoraStr As String
    Dim HorasOcupadas As Object: Set HorasOcupadas = CargaHorasOcupadas
    Dim HoraDeseada As Date
    Dim HoraOcupada As Boolean: HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Dim lrow4: lrow4 = Range("Z4").Row
    Dim lrow5: lrow5 = Range("Z5").Row
    Dim lrow6: lrow6 = Range("Z6").Row
    Dim lrow7: lrow7 = Range("Z7").Row
    Dim lrow8: lrow8 = Range("Z8").Row
    Dim lrow9: lrow9 = Range("Z9").Row
    Dim lrow10: lrow10 = Range("Z10").Row
    Dim lrow11: lrow11 = Range("Z11").Row
    Dim lrow12: lrow12 = Range("Z12").Row
    Dim lrow13: lrow13 = Range("Z13").Row
    Dim lrow14: lrow14 = Range("Z14").Row
    Dim lrow15: lrow15 = Range("Z15").Row
If Target.Address = "$Z$4" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C9")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z4").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z4").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow4, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$5" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C10")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z5").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z5").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow5, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$6" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z6").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C11")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z6").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z6").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$7" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C12")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z7").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z7").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$8" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z8").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C13")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z8").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z8").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$9" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z9").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C14")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z9").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z9").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$10" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C15")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z10").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z10").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$11" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z11").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C16")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z11").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z11").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
        Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$12" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z12").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C17")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z12").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z12").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$13" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C18")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z13").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z13").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$14" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z14").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C19")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z14").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z14").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
ElseIf Target.Address = "$Z$15" Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z15").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C20")
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z15").Copy
    Sheets("Tips").Range("K14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    HoraDeseada = Range("Z15").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    Do While HoraOcupada
        HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
        HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
        HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
        .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    End With
End If
End Sub

Private Function CargaHorasOcupadas() As Object
Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
Dim lrow As Long: lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
If lrow > 3 Then
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Hora As String
    For Each C In .Range("AB4:AB" & lrow)
        Hora = Format(C, "hh:mm")
        Dict.Add Hora, 1
    Next C
End If
End With
Set CargaHorasOcupadas = Dict
End Function
```

Comment: Un Diccionario es un objeto que no permite valores duplicados en su colección. Como nunca lo limpias y estás usando el evento `Worksheet_Change`, seguramente lo que está pasando es que estás intentando meter algo en el diccionario que ya existía. Vacía el diccionario en algún momento, o replantea tu código (¿no podías usar COUNTIF y ya?)

Comment: Como podría vaciar el diccionario? En cuanto al Count if fue por donde empece, pero no fui capaz de lograrlo

Comment: ObjetoDiccionaro.RemoveAll debería limpiarlo entero. En este enlace viene información muy útil https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: Al vaciar el objeto diccionario 'Dict.Removeall' ejecuta el código sin problemas pero no encuentra los valores anteriores y por lo tanto no suma 2 minutos, sino que muestra siempre el tiempo introducido. Si hubiera manera de almacenar los valores en una matriz e introducir dicho valor en esta cuando se comprueba que ya no existe.

Comment: Vale, entonces prueba otra cosa. En esa misma página que te pasé viene cómo comprobar si existe ya un elemento en el diccionario. Comprueba antes de añadir si existe: si no existe, entonces lo añades, y si existe, entonces no haces nada o actualizas su valor. Algo tipo `Dict.Exists(key)` te devuelve `True/False` si existe o no.